# Using zero-length xts objects

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I am confused by zero-length xts objects with a non-zero width, here for convenience addressed as  *empty* xts objects.
I think  they are a good way to model securities for which there are no observations, e.g. delisted securities.

```
x=xts(matrix(numeric(0), dimnames=list(NULL, "Delist1")), as.Date(numeric(0)))
x
#      Delist1
```

However, when it comes to merge empty securities, they simply disappear:

```
y=xts(1:3,  as.Date(1:3))    
names(y)="List1"
merge(x,y)
#             List1
# 1970-01-02      1
# 1970-01-03      2
# 1970-01-04      3
```

This is particularly inconvenient when you have several time series, some of which might be empty:

```
z=xts(matrix(numeric(0), dimnames=list(NULL, "Delist2")), as.Date(numeric(0)))
L=list(x,y,z) # etc.
Reduce(merge, L)
#             List1
# 1970-01-02      1
# 1970-01-03      2
# 1970-01-04      3
```

You lose the information about empty time series, while you would like to have a full column of NAs for each empty series.

Perhaps the simple rule of the thumb is simply not to use empty xts objects and use NAs:

```
x=c(Delist1=NA)
z=c(Delist2=NA)
L=list(x,y,z) # etc.
X=Reduce(merge.xts, L)
setNames(X, sapply(L, names))
#            Delist1  List1 Delist2
# 1970-01-02      NA      1      NA
# 1970-01-03      NA      2      NA
# 1970-01-04      NA      3      NA
```

However, the first two series can't be NAs:

```
L=list(x,z,y) # etc.
Reduce(merge.xts, L)
# Error use:
do.call(merge.xts, L)
```

Anyway, if all elements of `L` are empty,  `do.call(...)` still does not work and extra fixes are required.

Summing up:

1. How should empty xts objects be used?
2. Are they intended to model time series without observations?

## UPDATE

*This is a long comment to the solution proposed by @userR*

In my fictional time window `as.Date(1:3)`, it would be simple to create/define an empty time series with a NA for each date and this might work for theoretical cases.
In real world scenarios, when you query data along a given time window, you never get all days filled.

To clarify, say you query data for securities A and B over the period 2000-02-01/2000-02-04.
The NA-based empty series should be like:

```
(delist=xts(rep(NA,4), as.Date("2000-02-01")+0:3))
#            [,1]
# 2000-02-01   NA
# 2000-02-02   NA
# 2000-02-03   NA
# 2000-02-04   NA
```

Actual, data returned by provider, might be like:

```
A
#            [,1]
# 2000-02-01    1
# 2000-02-02    2
# 2000-02-03    3

B
#            [,1]
# 2000-02-01    1
# 2000-02-02   NA
# 2000-02-03    3
```

Assume there is no 2000-02-04 date because this is not a trading day.
Merging gives:

```
merge(A,B, delist)
#             A  B delist
# 2000-02-01  1  1     NA
# 2000-02-02  2 NA     NA
# 2000-02-03  3  3     NA
# 2000-02-04 NA NA     NA
```

Clearly the NA in [2,2] is an actual missing value, the last row of NAs is artificially induced by the definition of `delist`.
Instead, the single NA approach does not involve these problems:

```
delist=NA
merge(A,B, delist)
#            A  B delist
# 2000-02-01 1  1     NA
# 2000-02-02 2 NA     NA
# 2000-02-03 3  3     NA
```

We cannot know exactly in advance the trading dates returned. Different markets/exchanges/securities  implement different conventions, so identifying trading days before querying for them would be at least impractical, if at all possible.

### UPDATE: Persistence

There is also a more subtle issue.
Above, securities `A` and `B` have a persistent representation based on actual observations. When the context requires it, for example in a `merge()`, NAs are added to fill misalignment gaps.
Defining, as above,  a third security `C` based on the dates of `A` and `B` makes for a weak definition because, when you change the portfolio mix, you are also changing the definition of this security, but `C` is always the same security for which the data source returned no data.
So, IMHO,  `C` can be modelled as a `NA`, a `NULL`, a zero-length xts, etc., but not as a *context sensitive*  value.

Comment: I see what you mean. Am I correct to then assume that the number of NAs in your `delist` series _only_ depends on the number of rows in your longest series returned from your query? If this is the case, can you not create `delist` _after_ you query your data? This way you can have the property of not artificially adding more NAs than necessary while being able to store `delist` as a `xts` object. You can do something like this `xts(matrix(rep(NA, length(y)), dimnames=list(NULL, "Delist1")), order.by = index(y))`

Comment: Let me know if I am understanding this correctly, and I will edit my answer to accommodate.

Comment: @useR: To the scope of the merge, you can take any date from a non-empty series.
However I don't think it is a good idea to make a _definition_ of an object (the empty time series)  dependent on the values found in other objects.  You might not know in advance what dates will be fed and, more important, if you add or remove new securities, the _definition breaks_. It could be  better to redefine merge() in order to accept empty xts objects and produce a NA-column in the output.

Comment: I understand your concern, but I don't think there is an issue, because `delist` always has something to merge to, otherwise what is the point of analyzing `delist` alone? You can always define `delist` programmatically based on the longest series. That way you don't have to _know_ how long is the longest series, the program knows. After your merge, the `delist` column no longer depends on the initial definition, so removing any existing series would not break anything. I though agree that redefining `merge()` to accept an empty xts is a better idea, but I can't think of a solution thus far.

Comment: "empty" xts objects as you define them aren't well-defined in the code, and therefore not currently supported.  There are "zero-width" xts objects, which are xts objects that have an index, but no data.  Your "empty" object has no index, but has "columns" with no data.  I would call that "zero-length".  I've also opened [an issue](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts/issues/168) to document and discuss this subtle difference.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Fixed. Orginal name came from the practical use-case, when the data source returns no data. IMHO, the best is to represent a data query with no data through a zero-lenght xts, to keep object consistency. Unfortunately, they do not play nicely with `merge.xts()`. In `merge(A,B)`, if `A` has only `n` out of the `N` observation dates of `B`, the missing `N-n` observations are set to `NA`. If `n==0`, this should work the same. Perhaps during development, the thought was: `n==0` means nothing, let's discard it. But no data (including no dates) is a frequent practical case.

Answer (score 1):

*1. How should empty xts objects be used?*

*2. Are they intended to model time series without observations?*

Answer to both:

Empty xts objects often are the result of subsetting over a time range that is outside the range of values in your xts object.  What would you expect `getSymbols("AAPL"); AAPL["1900"]` to return?

When is an empty xts object useful then?  Well, I would create an empty `xts` object (no actual data) with a set of dates if I wanted to pad in rows of NA data, which might later be used for other purposes.  For example, if we have `bid/ask` values on uneven time stamps, we might want to create 5 second OHLC bars, with neat start of bar timestamps (NB in reality, if you are merging bar data at different frequencies, always be sure to use end of bar timestamps to avoid accidentally introducing lookforward bias).  An empty xts object helps reach the goal:

```
# Create sample tick data:
set.seed(5)
st_time <- as.POSIXct('2007-01-02 09:00:00')
x <- xts(x= matrix(c(1:10, 1:10 +0.01),nc = 2) + rnorm(10, 0, 0.01),
         order.by = st_time + rnorm(10,0, 3) + seq(5, 25, length.out = 10),
         dimnames = list(NULL, c("bid","ask")))
x
#                                   bid       ask
# 2007-01-02 09:00:04.816884  2.0138436  2.023844
# 2007-01-02 09:00:06.203266  2.9874451  2.997445
# 2007-01-02 09:00:08.682891  0.9915914  1.001591
# 2007-01-02 09:00:10.673608  5.0171144  5.027114
# 2007-01-02 09:00:11.194063  4.0007014  4.010701
# 2007-01-02 09:00:14.003655  7.9936463  8.003646
# 2007-01-02 09:00:15.694152  5.9939709  6.003971
# 2007-01-02 09:00:16.541393  6.9952783  7.005278
# 2007-01-02 09:00:23.500229  8.9971423  9.007142
# 2007-01-02 09:00:24.221933 10.0013811 10.011381

to.period(x, period = "secs", k = 5, indexAt='startof')
#                              x.Open    x.High     x.Low    x.Close
# 2007-01-02 09:00:04.816884 2.013844  2.013844 2.0138436  2.0138436
# 2007-01-02 09:00:06.203266 2.987445  2.987445 0.9915914  0.9915914
# 2007-01-02 09:00:10.673608 5.017114  7.993646 4.0007014  7.9936463
# 2007-01-02 09:00:15.694152 5.993971  6.995278 5.9939709  6.9952783
# 2007-01-02 09:00:23.500229 8.997142 10.001381 8.9971423 10.0013811

# 5 sec bar Timestamps are messy, so let's fix them using an empty xts object
# Use of an empty xts object:
emp_5sec_interval <- xts(order.by = st_time + seq(5, 25, by = 5),)
x2 <- merge(x, emp_5sec_interval, fill = na.locf)
x2
#                                   bid       ask
# 2007-01-02 09:00:04.816884  2.0138436  2.023844
# 2007-01-02 09:00:05.000000  2.0138436  2.023844
# 2007-01-02 09:00:06.203266  2.9874451  2.997445
# 2007-01-02 09:00:08.682891  0.9915914  1.001591
# 2007-01-02 09:00:10.000000  0.9915914  1.001591
# 2007-01-02 09:00:10.673608  5.0171144  5.027114
# 2007-01-02 09:00:11.194063  4.0007014  4.010701
# 2007-01-02 09:00:14.003655  7.9936463  8.003646
# 2007-01-02 09:00:15.000000  7.9936463  8.003646
# 2007-01-02 09:00:15.694152  5.9939709  6.003971
# 2007-01-02 09:00:16.541393  6.9952783  7.005278
# 2007-01-02 09:00:20.000000  6.9952783  7.005278
# 2007-01-02 09:00:23.500229  8.9971423  9.007142
# 2007-01-02 09:00:24.221933 10.0013811 10.011381
# 2007-01-02 09:00:25.000000 10.0013811 10.011381

x_ohlc <- to.period(x2, period = "secs", k = 5, indexAt='startof')
x_ohlc
#                               x2.Open   x2.High     x2.Low   x2.Close
# 2007-01-02 09:00:04.816884  2.0138436  2.013844  2.0138436  2.0138436
# 2007-01-02 09:00:05.000000  2.0138436  2.987445  0.9915914  0.9915914
# 2007-01-02 09:00:10.000000  0.9915914  7.993646  0.9915914  7.9936463
# 2007-01-02 09:00:15.000000  7.9936463  7.993646  5.9939709  6.9952783
# 2007-01-02 09:00:20.000000  6.9952783 10.001381  6.9952783 10.0013811
# 2007-01-02 09:00:25.000000 10.0013811 10.001381 10.0013811 10.0013811
```

---

If you want to model delisted securities, then create an xts object with valid dates, and fill the corresponding columns (likely more than one column in reality, such as OHLC, Bid/Ask) with NAs.  e.g. merge delisted securities using something like (As useR already suggests)

```
y=xts(rep(NA, 3),  as.Date(1:3))
```

I wouldn't use the `delist=NA` approach you suggest.

Ultimately the xts authors are the authority here on design in relation to what an empty xts object is ...

Comment: I would be careful to differentiate between "zero-width" and "zero-length", and would avoid using "empty" to describe either type of object.

Comment: Say you want to get data for S1, S2, S3... You loop them and, given a delisting, `getSymbols("S1")` returns an error. You capture it with a `try` and need to give a value to S1. Which one? If it depends on dates of S2, S3..., you do not know them in advance. So you can build S1 (and other empty time series) only at the end of the loop. How do you store S1 state in the meantime? Also good series might have different dates. With a different portfolio mix dates vary and you need to rebuild S1. We need first some kind of persistent value to model S1. Later S1 can be merged through NA observations.

Comment: @antonio so include a dummy first row of na values with the date being say 1970-01-01 or whatever for delisted securities. Then merge across securities normally (and subset out  values under a reasonable start date). Seems like you're over complicating things with how you want to initialize objects.  Look at blotter and quantstrat package source for inspiration on how others initialize xts objects. It's loosely related.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is how you define an "empty time series". The way you defined your "empty series" is that it has zero rows. Your first merge ignores `x` because it does not know how to work with zero length series.  `merge()` excludes your empty series because there are no common column to merge *by*. In fact, your delisted series should have 3 rows with NAs for each row. This way you can compare them with `xts` objects of the same number of rows.

```
library(xts)

x=xts(matrix(rep(NA, 3), dimnames=list(NULL, "Delist1")), as.Date(1:3))

y=xts(1:3,  as.Date(1:3))    
names(y)="List1"
z = merge(x,y)

# > z
#            Delist1 List1
# 1970-01-02      NA     1
# 1970-01-03      NA     2
# 1970-01-04      NA     3

class(z)

# > class(z)
# [1] "xts" "zoo"
```

Comment: Your idea works in theory does not in practice as days returned never follow an easily predefined pattern. I try to comment with details in the update.